# Using LeafletLoader instead of PDFLoader to load a PDF into the forge viewer is not working

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I want to load a large image into the forge viewer. I embedded the image in a pdf. However, when loading the pdf the vector pdf's resolution is not high enough and visibly worse than in the original pdf. Threfore, I am trying to load it via the LeafletLoader as described in this [blogpost](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/markups-leafletloader-vs-pdfloader). However, setting [`LMV_RASTER_PDF`](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/reference/globals/LMV_RASTER_PDF/) did not switch to the `LeafletLoader` (`LMV_VECTOR_PDF` is set to false). The loader used is still the `PDFLoader`.

Is there a setting I am missing or is there a way to load a leaflet map directly with the forge viewer? (LMV 7.40.0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **PDF** file needs to be translated to **SVF** - that's going to generate the **leaflets**.

https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/tutorials/prep-file4viewer/task3-translate-source-file/

Comment: That was my issue! As the leaflets are loaded on demand, is there a recommended way to use leaflets with the disconnected workflow? Using only the [service worker approach](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/disconnected-workflows) doesn't work nicely because if the user loses connection, more detailed images are not yet cached. According to this [blogpost](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/viewing-large-ocrterrain-images-forge-viewer) you could host / intercept requests via service workers yourself to serve the leaflet tiles by providing a custom blob.json. Is that a valid permitted approach?

Comment: I assume it's possible to figure out the rule of how the tiles for the PDF are stored, and then before going offline, programmatically run through all the possible tiles and fetch them, so that the service worker will store them.